# Preview is hidden and does not show

Tags: android-studio

I want to make android app. I have installed androis studio and now i have problem with it. The preview window is hidden

I have tried to fix this problem by updating everything that is possible, but after updating the window is not shown

[Image of android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmlnG.png)

You can see that i dont see screen where is running code

Android studio does not show me errors and
API is 22

Comment: try to Sync Project with Gradle Files and ReBuild the project again

Comment: @No Name i have already done this. Look at the picture (at the bottom)

Comment: clean and build project will do. also, try to change the view from text tab to design tab.

Comment: @No Name i have already done this 3 times. It did not help me

Answer (score 0):

You are using a bad version of constraint layout I would use the constraint layout from the androidx Library
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout I think is the tag

Answer (score 0):

- You can try to invalidate Caches and restart like this:

  File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...
  After you have done it try to reopen android studio and check your preview.
- Another solution that can help you is to switch from the `Text` tab to the `Design` tab, this is also the recommended option for working with `ConstraintLayout` + you can see your preview in your design tab.
- And if all of that didn't work you can always reinstall android studio again, this may be the less recommended option but it will most likely solve your problem.